# Implementing a macro recorder for a python gui?

Tags: python, user-interface, macros, recorder

I'm wondering how to go about implementing a macro recorder for a python gui (probably PyQt, but ideally agnostic). Something much like in Excel but instead of getting VB macros, it would create python code. Previously I made something for Tkinter where all callbacks pass through a single class that logged actions.  Unfortunately my class doing the logging was a bit ugly and I'm looking for a nicer one. While this did make a nice separation of the gui from the rest of the code, it seems to be unusual in terms of the usual signals/slots wiring. Is there a better way?

The intention is that a user can work their way through a data analysis procedure in a graphical interface, seeing the effect of their decisions. Later the recorded procedure could be applied to other data with minor modification and without needing the start up the gui.

Comment: Hi, this functionality is implemented really well in FreeCAD. For every action of the user a Python command appears in the Python console. Unfortunately I don't know how they do this, but I'd happy to.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking in high level, this is what I'd do:

Develop a decorator function, with which I'd decorate every event-handling functions.

This decorator functions would take note of thee function called, and its parameters  (and possibly returning values) in a unified data-structure - taking care, on this data structure, to mark Widget and Control instances as a special type of object. That is because in other runs these widgets won't be the same instances - ah, you can't even serialize a toolkit widget instances, be it Qt or otherwise.

When the time comes to play a macro, you fill-in the gaps replacing the widget-representating object with the instances of the actually running objects, and simply call the original functions with the remaining parameters.

In toolkits that have an specialized "event" parameter that is passed down to event-handling functions, you will have to take care of serializing and de-serializing this event as well.

I hope this can help. I could come up with some proof of concept code for that (although I am in a mood to use tkinter today - would have to read a lot to come up with a Qt4 example).

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the command design pattern: when your user executes an action, generate a command that represents the changes required.  You then implement some sort of command pipeline that executes the commands themselves, most likely just calling the methods you already have.  Once the commands are executed, you can serialize them or take note of them the way you want and load the series of commands when you need to re-execute the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

An example of what you're looking for is in [mayavi2](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/docs/development/html/mayavi/application.html#automatic-script-generation).  For your purposes, mayavi2's "script record" functionality will generate a Python script that can then be trivially modified for other cases.  I hear that it works pretty well.